# The colors on KMPlayer are a bit off in comparision to mpv

Tags: video, windows-11, colors, kmplayer

[image: Compartison]

Okay so watching a 4k video downloaded from YT and played on mpv and KMPlayer side by side and colors are slightly off on KM. Any fixes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what icc profile is the video using; what profile does each player think it is; is your display calibrated?

Comment: Try changing the renderer using [this](https://answers.informer.com/127443/settings-kmplayer-make-major-impact-video-processing-quality#:~:text=The%20quality%20of,Scaler%20to%20Bilinear.) guide?

Comment: Are the two players using the same codec for playing this video ?